# PL/SQL can you help me understand this PL/SQL code?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have this code in PL/SQL about the usage of DBMS_SQL; what does the ":sal" do when I assign the string sqlString?

```
DECLARE

sqlString VARCHAR2(100);

c INTEGER;

rows_processed INTEGER;

max_salary INTEGER;


BEGIN
max_salary := 10000;   
sqlString := 'DELETE FROM employees WHERE salary > :sal';    
c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, sqlString, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);    
DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(c, ':sal', max_salary);

rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Impiegati cancellati: ' || rows_processed);

DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);

END;
```

Comment: it is a bind parameter.  Think of it as a placeholder to contain the value.  When dbms_sql.execute is called, the :sal parameter gets populated with the value of max_salary.,

Comment: On a side note: If I am not missing something, there is no need for dynamic SQL here at all. You could directly issue `DELETE FROM employees WHERE salary > max_salary` and this would still use a bind variable, because this is how PL/SQL makes its variables known to the SQL engine. You'd get the number of processed rows with `SQL%ROWCOUNT` then. It is considered good style to use some prefix for PL/SQL variables, e.g. `v_max_salary`. Thus we can easily see in `DELETE FROM employees WHERE salary > v_max_salary` which is a variable and which is a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very well explained here:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_plsql_dbms_sql_bind_variable.htm

It simply assigns the values of "max_salary" to the sal variable. This is used for dynamic SQL procedures.

The code is executing this query (sal = max_salary = 10000):

```
DELETE FROM employees WHERE salary > 10000
```

In the end it shows how many records have been deleted.